# TSQL - how to get the MAX of multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max, multiple-columns

I have a table with

```
EMPLOYEE_CODE, 
ENTITLEMENT_CODE, 
TRANS_DATE, 
UNIQUE_ID, 
HOURS.
```

I need to get the HOURS for the maximum `TRANS_DATE` for each combination of `EMPLOYEE_CODE`, `ENTITLEMENT_CODE` but it is possible there will multiple occurances of the maximum TRANS_DATE so I need to further refine to query to get the maximum of the `UNIQUE_ID` and hence the HOURS for this particular row that returned.  I've tried various methods but I can get part of the query but not the whole thing together.

So I might have something like:

```
EMPLOYEE_CODE,  ENTITLEMENT_CODE,   TRANS_DATE, UNIQUE_ID,  HOURS.
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2305            ANNL                04/15/2014  28547       15.55
2305            ANNL                04/15/2014  28622       16.83
2305            ANNL                04/15/2014  28223       18.62
2305            ANNL                04/08/2014  28111       12.22
2305            SICK                04/12/2014  28150       14.47
2305            SICK                04/12/2014  28162       12.44
2305            SICK                03/11/2014  28062       18.66
```

So this would need to return

```
16.83 for 2305 ANNL 
12.44 for 2305 SICK
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_CODE, ENTITLEMENT_CODE
                         ORDER BY TRANS_DATE DESC, UNIQUE_ID DESC) rn
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT 
  EMPLOYEE_CODE, 
  ENTITLEMENT_CODE, 
  HOURS
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

**[SQL FIFFLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b776/1)**

Comment: This worked well Hamlet.  I haven't used CTE before so I'll study it a bit more to improve my understanding but the query returned what I expected.  Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `row_number()` with `partition by clause`

```
select * from
(
select *,rn=row_number()over(partition by ENTITLEMENT_CODE order by UNIQUE_ID desc)
from table
)x
where x.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT HOURS, EMPLOYEE_CODE, ENTITLEMENT_CODE
FROM mytable T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable T2
    WHERE  T2.EMPLOYEE_CODE    = T1.EMPLOYEE_CODE
      AND  T2.ENTITLEMENT_CODE = T1.ENTITLEMENT_CODE
      AND (T2.TRANS_DATE > T1.TRANS_DATE
        OR T2.TRANS_DATE = T1.TRANS_DATE AND T2.UNIQUE_ID > T1.UNIQUE_ID)
)
```

You should preferably have an index over `EMPLOYEE_CODE` and `ENTITLEMENT_CODE` (compositely) for this to work efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

May be Something Like this

```
 Select T.* From Table1 T JOIN
   ( Select Max(S.UNIQUE_ID) MaxUniq,S.EMPLOYEE_CODE,S.ENTITLEMENT_CODE
     From Table1 S Join
        ( Select T1.EMPLOYEE_CODE,T1.ENTITLEMENT_CODE,Max(T1.TRANS_DATE) As MaxDate
          From Table1 T1 Group By T1.EMPLOYEE_CODE,T1.ENTITLEMENT_CODE
        ) JR On S.TRANS_DATE = JR.MaxDate AND S.EMPLOYEE_CODE = JR.EMPLOYEE_CODE AND S.ENTITLEMENT_CODE = JR.ENTITLEMENT_CODE
         Group By S.EMPLOYEE_CODE,S.ENTITLEMENT_CODE
 )R ON T.UNIQUE_ID = R.MaxUniq
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d8b5/1)**

*Output Would be:*

---

```
EMPLOYEE_CODE   ENTITLEMENT_CODE    TRANS_DATE  UNIQUE_ID   HOURS
2305            ANNL                2014-04-15  28622       16.83
2305            SICK                2014-04-12  28162       12.44
```

Comment: This worked well Vignesh and returned what I expected.  I'm not sure if this has advantages over the CTE solution posted.  Your help is appreciated.